# What other ways are there to make a Wizard more intelligent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

There are four ways I know of to get your intelligence increased as a Wizard:

- Levelling to get stat bonus (Untyped, 5 by level 20)
- [Headband of vast intelligence](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/headband-of-vast-intelligence) (+2 to +6 enhancement bonus)
- [Crimson Sphere Ioun Stone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/crimson-sphere-ioun-stone) (+2 to +6 enhancement bonus, stacks with itself only)
- [Tome of clear thought](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/book-tome-of-clear-thought) (+1 to +5 Inherent, permanent, same as 'Wish')

This limits a wizard to a 'measly' maximum of 36 intelligence: base 18 + 2 (race) + 6 (headband or stones) + 5 (levels) + 5 (tome).

What other ways that will stack with these can a Wizard increase their intelligence?

Polymorphing (or race changing) is semi-acceptable, but this is not a ideal solution as a permanent bonus is preferred without changing race.

Comment: Math camp? :)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Become a Lich

[Pathfinder Lich Template](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lich)

You get +2 to Intelligence for forsaking your humanity.

*Mind you, this means you value your own humanity at 4,000 gold and are willing to pay 120,000 gold.*

> **Creating a Lich:** Each lich must create its own phylactery by using the Craft Wondrous Item feat. The character must be able to cast spells and have a caster level of 11th or higher. The phylactery costs 120,000 gp to create and has a caster level equal to that of its creator at the time of creation.

Comment: At 4,000 gold and +2 int! After all that's the reason we're becoming liches: for smarts!

Comment: The 4,000 gold is for the equivalent price of the +2 Int. It's actually much more expensive to become a Lich, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 9):

There is at least two other options that I know of to increase your intelligence:

- The easiest and less likely to be removed/ban/get you a book in the face : Just let the time pass... Yes growing old will net you a bonus to your mental stat, albeit at the price of your physical abilities! You can look at the [Aging Table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/description). By the time you get venerable you have earn a +3 to all mental stats and a -6 to all physical ones.
- This one is quite iffy in the sense that it rely on the [Mythic adventure](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic). This set of rules will give you access to power closing the gap between you and the gods. Along your progression through 10 tiers (10 level progression) you will gain 10 more untyped bonus (5 times +2 to any stat). Using those rules, there is also a Tier-3 path ability granting you a +2. It is called Enhanced Ability. 
  **This is a subset of rules that I would refrain from using unless I plan on matching the opposition, even under-optimized characters will trivially wreck regular (non mythic) encounters.**

Comment: The age table caps mental bonuses to +1. After Middle-aged, there is no benefit to aging.

Comment: Bonus for age is untyped so it stacks with itself. It is explained clearly in the text accompanying the table I linked to: " The effects of each aging step are cumulative. "

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Append that little addendum to the post.

Comment: @Harmelyo which mythic feat are you using that gives a +2 bonus to an ability score?

Comment: @royalmurder Apology this is not a mythic feat but a  Tier-3 Universal Path ability called Enhanced Ability. I was reading my character sheet poorly and did not notice I used a Feat to take an extra path ability...

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the previous answers, you could consider taking the "[Dragon Disciple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/core-rulebook/dragon-disciple)" prestige class from the core book : the 8th level grants a +2 INT bonus.

Then of course, combine the effects of aging, enchanted items, or mythic tier bonuses as Harmelyo suggested.
You can have up to 52 INT

`18 (base) + 10 (mythic path) + 6 (headband or stone) + 5 (levels) + 5 (tome) + 2 (mythic path ability) + 2 (prestige class) + 2 (race) + 2 (lich)`

Comment: @Glaerferyn It was pointed out to me that I made a mistake and the +2 was not from a mythic feat but a path ability (Tier 3: called Enhanced Ability)

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to gain a second CR +1 template, after becoming a Lich, you could become an [*Advanced Creature*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/advanced-creature-cr-1), and as such gain a further +4 to your intelligence, amongst your other stats.

Combined with advancement to Venerable age, [*which can be seen on this PRD page*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/ageHeightWeight.html), which nets you a further untyped +3 bonus to your intelligence, and the methods mentioned in your question, you will be at a plump total of: 18+2+5+5+6+4+3 = **43 Intelligence**

Then, if the [*Mythic Adventures*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic) rules are used, and you ascend to the lofty heights of Mythic Rank 10, you can receive a further +10 bonus to your Intelligence.
Combining this with the [3rd tier Path Ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/mythic/mythic-heroes/#3rd-Tier_Universal_Path_Abilities) *Enhanced Ability*, nets you a possible maximum, without adding any other templates, **55 Intelligence** ability score!
<sup>With a measly -2 on your Strength / Dexterity / Constitution ability scores after ability score generation and racial modifiers, and a +7 on your Wisdom and Charisma!</sup>

If the wizard in question somehow also gains control over a [Succubus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/succubus/), or is daring enough to strike a deal with one, then they can also gain a +2 profane bonus. (Although I would very much encourage any player willing to do this to consider the implications of a Succubus having direct telepathic access to their minds!) This would get you to a net total of **57 Intelligence!**
<sup>That's a +23 modifier?! Yeesh!</sup>

---

Note: Not many DMs will allow you to take so many templates, but those that do are probably applying them or using similarly terrifying encounters against you, so be warned!

Comment: And a further +2 from the profane bonus from the succubus (see below) = 57!

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional way to gain a further +2; A [succubus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/succubus/) can grant a +2 profane bonus to a stat of their choice. This can however be dismissed at any time by the succubus!